# iOS/iCal switches times over daylight savings with recurring event from ICS file

Tags: ios, icalendar, dst

I have an event that is set up using UTC and it recurs over daylight savings time. After the daylight savings time switch, the time is moved an hour. UTC does not use DST, so the time should stay the same. I can add an event after DST with the EXACT same UTC time value and the calendar shows the correct time. I've posted my ICS File below with the recurring event and the one that happens after. Has anyone run into this? Any suggested fixes or changes?

["BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//sethhill v1.0//NONSGML //EN\nCALSCALE:GREGORIAN\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTAMP:20120725T222602Z\nDTSTART:20120724T180000Z\nDTEND:20120724T183000Z\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20130707T180000Z\nSUMMARY:Class 4  - NODST\nBEGIN:VALARM\nTRIGGER:-PT45M\nACTION:DISPLAY\nDESCRIPTION:NODST\nEND:VALARM\nEND:VEVENT\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTAMP:20120725T222602Z\nDTSTART:20121120T190000Z\nDTEND:20121120T193000Z\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20130707T180000Z\nSUMMARY:Class 4  - TEST1DST\nBEGIN:VALARM\nTRIGGER:-PT45M\nACTION:DISPLAY\nDESCRIPTION:TEST1DST\nEND:VALARM\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong about how DST and UTC work. I was thinking that having a set UTC time meant that the calendar would read it as a set time and display the correct local time auto-magically. In case anyone else is a little confused, think of it like this: MST is UTC-07:00    MDT (DST) is UTC-06:00. If you have a calendar event that is set to repeat throughout the year and it is 18:00 UTC, it will be at 12:00PM MDT or 11:00AM MST. For an ICS file you can either define a STANDARD timezone and a DAYLIGHT timezone, or break the event into multiple parts, with the correct UTC time for each.

I hope this clears things up for someone else.

Comment: A specific example of what you did to fix it would be very helpful.

Comment: I ended up going the route of splitting up the event into two parts. One with a correlating UTC time before DST, one with the correct UTC after DST. Would an ICS file that does this help you out?

Comment: could you post the example of what you did? I have same issue with the DST, don't know how you slipt a recurrent appointment in two, one before DST and other after... and even if you do so, how you get the information on when the time changes to know the first date with the new time? I mean, do you store information of all timezones in your app? do you connect to any web service? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @PalomaCallejo, I wrote a function to get the daylight savings start date and end date for a given year and timezone. I'll attach it in an answer below. I was creating the ICS files server side to be consumed by the App via a web service. Since I was writing the ICS files my self, I would just create the Events in the ICS file to stop right before DST, and then a new event to start +/- 1 hour after DST had occurred.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DateTime GetDSTStart(int year, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
        {
            DateTime finder = new DateTime(year,3,8);
            finder = finder.AddHours(6);
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                if(timeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(finder.AddDays(i))){
                    return (finder.AddDays(i).AddHours(-6));
                }
            }
            finder = DateTime.MinValue;
            return finder;
        }

public static DateTime GetDSTEnd(int year, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
        {
            DateTime finder = new DateTime(year, 11, 1);
            finder = finder.AddHours(6);
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                if (!timeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(finder.AddDays(i)))
                {
                    return (finder.AddDays(i).AddHours(-6));
                }
            }
            finder = DateTime.MinValue;
            return finder;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

iCal displays your calendar in your local time zone (or one you can set manually), but not UTC.

In an region using daylight saving time, the mapping from UTC to local time will change depending on the date.  Thus, if the ics file has the date in UTC it will exhibit the problem you described.  You need to:

1. store the time zone ID,
2. and also the definition of the time zone ID you use, mapping from the ID to the actual UTC offset, in your ics file.

Part 2 might not be needed on some systems, but it is better to store the TZID right in your file for maximum portablility.